# Autocompletion of email addresses in vim

Tags: vim, email, autocomplete

I'm playing around with various bits of an email solution, including notmuch and alot.  I write my emails in vim and I'd like to have tab completion of email addresses while writing email.  Is there a general plugin that would do something like this for me?

Ideally it would have a variable for what command to run and write and accept one of the standard address book formats - say mutt's format.

Plugins I've found so far:

- [email.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/email.vim/blob/master/plugin/email.vim) - basic and based on a single text file, but probably the easiest to hack if I can't find anything better
- [lbdbq](https://github.com/vim-scripts/lbdbq) and [lbdbQuery.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/LbdbQuery.vim) which both use lbdb

The addressbook I'm currently using is [nottoomuch-addresses](http://www.guru-group.fi/~too/nottoomuch/nottoomuch-addresses/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own custom insert-mode completion, and `:imap` that for easy access. There's an example in the help at `:help E840` that shows the boilerplate; you just need to implement the email address query, probably either with `system()` or `readfile()`.